# Use chrome native dynamic import() in webpack 3.10

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to use the native chrome support for dynamic import() but webpack wants to do code splitting on my `import()`.

Basically I have `const m = await import("./path/foo")` and I want webpack to leave that alone without doing anything with it so it can pass through to chrome's native import(). Is there any way to configure webpack like this?

See here for info on the native import() support in chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import

Answer (score 0):

I have "solved" this by going the alternative route of simply using `fetch("./path/foo)` but it would indeed be nice to know how this should actually be done.